# send http put request in werkzeug

Tags: python, httplib, werkzeug

in my web app, I use werkzeug to listen and process requests. In one of the functionalities, I need to listen to request(say from A) and send an http put request to another server (B), then after I get response from B, I respond A an response.

I am not very familiar with werkzeug, and not sure if it has ability to send out requests, so I used httplib to send requests.

But I am getting errors.

There are a lot of moving parts, I am wondering the following:
1. does werkzeug have ability to send out requests
2. what is the cause of the error

Appreciate any help.

Code:

```
def complete(self, request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        location_id = self.extract_param_value(request,'location_id');
        status_code = self.extract_param_value(request,'status_code');

        req_url = something;
        jsonData = { 'data' : {'status' : status_code, 'id': location_id}};
        jsonDataDump = json.dumps(jsonData);
        #send request to B
        connection =  httplib.HTTPConnection(HOST, timeout=5);
        body_content = jsonDataDump;
        headers = {"Content-type": "application/json", "Accept": "text/plain"};
        connection.request('PUT', req_url, body_content, headers); #error occurs here
        result = connection.getresponse();
        connection.close();
        #return response to A
        response = Response(status=200);

        return response;
```

Error:

```
        1**.1**.1**.** - - [30/Dec/2011 03:06:57] "GET //complete?location_id=615201308&status_code=LIVE&message=fine HTTP/1.1" 500 -
        Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/ec2-user/y_ws.py", line 381, in __call__
        return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
        File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Werkzeug-0.8.1-py2.6.egg/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 411, in __call__
            return self.app(environ, start_response)
          File "/home/ec2-user/y_ws.py", line 377, in wsgi_app
            response = self.dispatch_request(request);
          File "/home/ec2-user/y_ws.py", line 98, in dispatch_request
            return getattr(self, endpoint)(request, **values)
          File "/home/ec2-user/y_ws.py", line 184, in complete
           connection.request('PUT', y_req_url, body_content, headers);
          File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 914, in request
            self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
          File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 951, in _send_request
            self.endheaders()
          File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 908, in endheaders
            self._send_output()
          File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 780, in _send_output
            self.send(msg)
          File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 739, in send
            self.connect()
          File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 720, in connect
            self.timeout)
          File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/socket.py", line 567, in create_connection
            raise error, msg
        error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Werkzeug is not a library for making HTTP requests, use httplib (as in your example)
2. Check with curl if the request succeeds from the host machine to rule out network issues. The error you are getting is general network error.